# Minimizing a threshold in Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I would like to minimize a threshold using the scipy minimize function. This is a constrained minimization where my constraints are the output of the kernel ridge predictor function.

To be more precise, I have a data set, I train the Kernel Ridge method in scikit-learn and for a given test case, I would like to minimize a threshold while selecting one value of the test vector which would make the threshold feasible.

Here is the code

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
     'fun': lambda x:  x[0]-Krr.predict(np.concatenate(([x[1]],    [np.transpose(xTest[1:])]), axis=0))})

fun = lambda x: x[0]
res = minimize(fun,(0,0),constraints=cons)
```

In this code x[0] is a threshold and x[1] is a value I would like to find that fits the constraint. This is why the objective does not take into account x[1].

When I run this code, it tells me that the arguments of np.concatenate must have the same dimensions: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions".

Here x[1] should be a single float, and xTest[1:] should be an np array for example, 1xN.

Since this is a problem while running minimize, how can I troubleshoot this to align the arrays?

Better yet, has anyone performed such a minimization?

Comment: Start by checking the shapes of ```x[1]``` and ```np.transpose(xTest[1:])``` used inside the constraint. You should do this interactively and outside of scipy.optimize to learn the source of the error. Later, when the bug was fixed, think about a good minimizer as it's possible that your task is more suited for derivative-free optimization as function-evaluations can be costly! **Edit:** maybe it's even better to use ```minimize_scalar``` and use some kind of global access to the remaining parts of x (as scalar-optimization is much more simple).

Comment: Sascha, this exact program line works outside of scipy.optimize.  I suspect the problem is that "x" is the variable generated during the optimization.

Comment: It's part of the constraints, so it's called within minimize. Why try to debug it within some complex function. Just observe the error with some inspection-code without minimize. It will probably fail there as well.

Comment: I realize that this is within the constraints in the code snippet I provided, but this is very simplified code for the question.  In practice I use this exact line with no problems outside minimize: Krr.predict(np.concatenate(([x[1],[np.transpose(xTest[1:])]), axis=0)).... This is a problem internal to the minimize function.

Comment: Then show a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*.